# Importing csv file cyrillic characters to Mysql - PHPMyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, import, alphabetical

Hello hard question here,

I am trying to import a csv file with cyrillic characters such as (RUSSIAN cities, they may be over 40.000) - This is displayed in the notepad++ editor with the encoding set to UTF-8 without bom -:

```
RU,101000,Москва,Москва,,,,,,55.7522,37.6156,4
RU,101194,Москва 194,Москва,,,,,,55.7522,37.6156,1
RU,101300,Москва 300,Москва,,,,,,55.7522,37.6156,1
```

and then I import it using the import tab in phpmyadmin.
once when I browse the data imported. I have the following characters:

```
RU  101000  ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°     ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°
RU  101194  ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð° 194     ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°
RU  101300  ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð° 300     ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°
```

I've already set up the database to utf8_general_ci, I tried utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_lithuanian_ci... I do not know what to do to force an utf8 display in the phpmyadmin panel.
Is there a solution to import the data trhogh with a SQL input?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I guess it's fault of phpmyadmin rather than mysql.. Do you have shell access to the server?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not have access to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to the connection pipe phpMyAdmin is using to connect to the MySQL server.

According to [this solution](http://forum.coppermine-gallery.net/index.php/topic,59918.msg297139.html), phpMyAdmin uses `cpg_db_connect()` to connect to your db server and it needs to be updated to include `SET NAMES 'utf8'`. They give the following example:

```
function cpg_db_connect()
{
        global $CONFIG;
        $result = @mysql_connect($CONFIG['dbserver'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);
        if (!$result) {
                return false;
        }
        if (!mysql_select_db($CONFIG['dbname']))
                return false;
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $result); # <-- see here
        return $result;
}
```

If you cannot edit your phpMyAdmin install (say you're on a shared server), just install phpMyAdmin on your own site in a virtual/subdirectory and then find and edit this function. phpMyAdmin is just a php site like any other.

The purer way to do this (especially if you have character concerns) would be to import the data over ssh using mysql (e.g. `mysql -u dbuser -p dbname < import.sql`).

Comment: Sorry, I may not understand your solution but... I am not even using the code to read the data. I am using the phpmyadmin panel only. I am importing data from a csv file through the phpadmin panel... I'm already using mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8") for pretty much anything. thanks anyways

Comment: You may use PHP to directly insert data? isn't it?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to be clearer. The essence of this all is that the code your phpMyAdmin uses to connect to your MySQL server needs to be updated to to include use `SET NAMES 'utf8'`.

Comment: Lol thanks but how would you do this from a strict SQL point of view?  I tried this:    "SET NAMES utf8;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\wamp\\www\\testru.csv' INTO TABLE `postal_code` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" and does not work.

Comment: Think about it... You're trying to fix the problem from within the problem. You can't do it as you're asking. That's why -- if you spend some time searching for the problem -- you will see everyone else with your same problem fixes it in this way.